# PHP/HTML - Same size of column containing columns

Tags: php, html

I need some help to be able to match the same size between the first column and the group of four other columns. Yet I tried with solution [MatchHeight](http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/) and [row-eq-height](http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/). i tried also with a table. The main problem is that it brake the responsive tool.

I'm using bootstrap 3.3.6

Here is the sample I'm working with:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 bg-success">
      <div class="small-box">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12">
            <h3>Colonne 1</h3>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ultrices massa ligula, a faucibus nisi scelerisque sit amet. Sed cursus, urna eu suscipit egestas, dui dui luctus purus, malesuada pellentesque dolor dolor ac augue. Duis ac rutrum massa,
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 bg-warning">
      <div class="small-box">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
            <h3>Colonne 2</h3>
            <p>
              Donec in venenatis enim. Fusce mollis dui a est pharetra mollis. Pellentesque rhoncus, sem nec tempus tincidunt, ligula velit condimentum sapien, non ullamcorper ipsum mi vitae ante. Donec justo neque, euismod ut dapibus ac, varius sit amet ante. Nullam
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
            <h3>Colonne 3</h3>
            <p>
              Donec in venenatis enim. Fusce mollis dui a est pharetra mollis. Pellentesque rhoncus, sem nec tempus tincidunt, ligula velit condimentum sapien, non ullamcorper ipsum mi vitae ante. Donec justo neque, euismod ut dapibus ac, varius sit amet ante. Nullam
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
            <h3>Colonne 4</h3>
            <p>
              Donec in venenatis enim. Fusce mollis dui a est pharetra mollis. Pellentesque rhoncus, sem nec tempus tincidunt, ligula velit condimentum sapien, non ullamcorper ipsum mi vitae ante. Donec justo neque, euismod ut dapibus ac, varius sit amet ante. Nullam
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
            <h3>Colonne 5</h3>
            <p>
              Donec in venenatis enim. Fusce mollis dui a est pharetra mollis. Pellentesque rhoncus, sem nec tempus tincidunt, ligula velit condimentum sapien, non ullamcorper ipsum mi vitae ante. Donec justo neque, euismod ut dapibus ac, varius sit amet ante. Nullam
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

One of the constraint is to have two rows on the right. I can't just make one unique row.

A real thank to who would like to help and to those who are able to.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all `<div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-6">` with `<div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-3">`

Comment: edited question, a constraint is to have 2 rows on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's not an easy deal.

You can use "Flex-Box" (check that : https://codepen.io/imohkay/pen/gpard) if the "accessibility" of your projet can permit it (not good for IE9 etc. : https://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox). But I guess it's already what "row-eq-height" is doing...

Then, you can do it easily with jQuery.

Try something like :

```
var autoHeightResize = function (selector) {
    // Not on responsive
    if($(window).width() < 1024) return false;

    var maxheight = 0;
    var items = $(selector);
    // Whats is the max height ?
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        maxheight = Math.max(maxheight, $(items[i]).height());
    }
    // Resize block with max-height
    items.height(maxheight);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    // Init '#mypage .columns' auto-height resize
   var selectorAutoHeightBlocs = '#mypage .columns';
   autoHeightResize(selectorAutoHeightBlocs);
   // update columns height on resize page
   $(window).resize(function() { 
        autoHeightResize(selectorAutoHeightBlocs);
   });
});
```

In your case, you should give a same class name to your div *"col-xs-6 bg-success"* and *"col-xs-6 bg-warning"* (ex: `class="my-same-height-column"` ).

And then, use it in 'selectorAutoHeightBlocs' in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend you keep the same relation to small and extra small screen. 
But there it is:

With Table:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .first-col {
    width: 50%;
  }
  table th{
    width: 12.5%; /* (50/4) */
  }
</style>
<div class="responsive-table">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="first-col"></td>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

Tableless:

```
<div class="row">
  <!-- First Column -->
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
    <!-- Content -->
  </div>

  <!-- Small Ones -->
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: table-responsive creates a frame which keeps the size relation and maintain your content readable in small screens.